I have an azure data exploror as part of IaC ARM definition. Along side that, I have a script that with formatting and mapping rules
The script is passed in as a parameter(string). When I run my deployment, the pipeline can't parse the cript and throw an error. I tried to use escape or single quote in 'JsonTelemetryMapping'. That didnt fix my issue. The bellow script is used inside double quotes "" and passed as parameter inside the script resource code block. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The scipt is as follows:
.create table telemetry (

                DeviceId: string,
                CreationDateTime: datetime,
                Data: dynamic
            )
            .alter table telemetry policy streamingingestion enable
            .create table telemetry ingestion json mapping 'JsonTelemetryMapping'
            '['
            '{"Column": "DeviceId", "Properties": {"Path": "$.DeviceId"}}',
            '{"Column": "CreationDateTime", "Properties": {"Path": "$.iothub-enqueuedtime"}}',
            '{"Column": "Data", "Properties": {"Path": "$"}}'
            ']'

I used escapes, but to no avail.
It seemed to have solved json parsing issue. But it gave me a syntax error when trying to execute the command "create". Any idea what that could be from??

What error was thrown?

The error you are encountering is due to incorrect string concatenation or escaping when constructing the JSON mapping string inside a script block.
When using double quotes for the entire script and then trying to include JSON mappings inside, special characters like quotes and brackets need to be  escaped.

I Used this MsDOC to Ingest JSON formatted data into Azure Data Explorer .Learn

.create table telemetry (
    DeviceId: string,
    CreationDateTime: datetime,
    Data: dynamic
)


.create table telemetry ingestion json mapping 'JsonTelemetryMapping' '[{\"Column\":\"DeviceId\",\"Properties\":{\"Path\":\"$.DeviceId\"}},{\"Column\":\"CreationDateTime\",\"Properties\":{\"Path\":\"$.iothub-enqueuedtime\"}},{\"Column\":\"Data\",\"Properties\":{\"Path\":\"$\"}}]'


In the JSON mapping, every double quote " inside the string needs to be escaped with a backslash \.
I used this  MSDOC  to Create an IoT Hub data connection  in  Azure Data Explorer.


Thanks for the reply. I tried that but didnt work. It was still throwing a json based error. So, I had to use "\n" line break at every statement and with every brackect. like this:

.create-or-alter table telemetry (\n    DeviceId: string,\n    CreationDateTime: datetime,\n    Data: dynamic\n)\n.alter table telemetry policy streamingingestion enable\n.create-or-alter table telemetry ingestion json mapping 'JsonTelemetryMapping'\n[\n    {"Column": "DeviceId", "Properties": {"Path": "$.DeviceId"}},\n    {"Column": "CreationDateTime", "Properties": {"Path": "$.iothub-enqueuedtime"}},\n    {"Column": "Data", "Properties": {"Path": "$"}}\n].

It seemed to have solved json parsing issue. But it gave me a syntax error when trying to execute the command "create". Any idea what that could be from??

Refer this DOC for Syntax of  (.create | .alter | .create-or-alter) external table TableName

Hi Naveen. The solution @Sampath proposed was not enough. We had to add more line breaks. This did solve the json paring error, but failed at processing the command ."create-or-alter". Not sure what that is from.

Now, I am getting the following wrror:ScriptFailed: [BadRequest] Failed to run script 'scriptName' on database '****'. Here is a list of the commands that failed: Command: .create-or-alter table telemetry (
DeviceId: string,
CreationDateTime: datetime,
Data: dynamic
)  Reason: Syntax error:
